# TypeScript & JavaScript: Communicate using events with content

Tags: javascript, typescript, events, ecmascript-6, publish-subscribe

I have implemented the following service to communicate between a Javascript and a TypeScript module using events. This works fine, but in addition to just transmitting the events, I would like to send an object with the event, at least in some cases. However, I have no idea how to start. Any hints?

```
export interface IEventNotifcationService {
    subscribe(event: MyEvent, callback: () => void);
    emit(event: MyEvent);
}

export class EventNotifcationService implements IEventNotifcationService {

    static serviceId = 'myServiceID';

    callbacks: { [key: number]: (() => void)[] } = {};

    constructor(private $timeout: ng.ITimeoutService) {
        for (const event in MyEvent) {
            this.callbacks[event] = [];
        }
    }

    subscribe(event: MyEvent, callback: () => void) {
        this.callbacks[event].push(callback);
    }

    emit(event: MyEvent) {
        for (const callback of this.callbacks[event]) {
            this.$timeout(callback, 0);
        }
    }
}

export enum MyEvent {
    A = 'A',
    B = 'B',
    C = 'C'
}
```

Comment: `15` is an `int`

Answer (score 1):

You should update `subscribe` and `emit`.

```
subscribe(event: MyEvent, callback: () => void) {
        this.callbacks[event].push(callback);
    }

emit(event: MyEvent) {
        for (const callback of this.callbacks[event]) {
            this.$timeout(callback(event), 0);
        }
    }
```

Here's how you'd define your callback

```
let listener = (event) => {
  console.log('event occurred. data from the event:', event);
}

service.subscribe(listener)
```

Comment: Ok thanks, and how can I then retrieve the data from the subscriber side?

Comment: You add an argument to the `callback` definition where you are passing it to `subscribe` so that callback has access to the data and you'd have access to it.

Comment: Ah I see. So in my case, I would add an additional argument like content. THanksè